# Google Maps API keys proper usage

Tags: wordpress, api, google-maps

With the recent changes in Google Maps API key requirements, i am wondering on what is the proper way of implementing this.

We are a web agency with a lot of clients and most if not all use Google Maps. We use Wordpress platform for our websites.

So i decided to create a separate project for each client and create 1 key per project and all seemed fine. Now after about 10 projects, i am getting a notice that in order to increase limit i need to make a request and that contains a form with various data.

My questions are:

1. How many API keys i am allowed per project? Can i create batches for my clients; i.e. GROUP 1 project which contains 50 API keys for 50 different sites. Is this considered OK? if not how can i do this? I have done something similar in Google ReCaptcha, because it had a limit that blocked you viewing all your keys.
2. Should i create one project with one key, and then use that key in all of the websites which i would list them as allowed referrer urls?

If anyone can elaborate on how i can achieve this in the most appropriate way it would be great.

PS: The format of the URL under referrer is also causing me another headache. Some sites are fine with *.domain.com/* , others require http://domain.com. Is this normal? and if so why? Shouldn't the first option cover every other option? Is this due to DNS entries missing or misconfigured?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your needs, like what Google says on their help section (of the developer console)

> You can use one project to manage all of your work, or you can create multiple projects, depending on your development and collaboration needs. Before creating a project, you should consider whether you're collaborating with a different team of people, want to track usage differently, or need to set different traffic controls for different parts of your work. If so, breaking up your work into multiple projects might make sense.

Though they didn't provide a specific number of projects to be created, there are [limits to how many projects can be created](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en). It protects the community from unforseen spike of usages. As indicated, you'll need to create a quest to increase the quota.

For the HTTP Referrers, it allows wildcard to be set. I don't think a `*.example.com` will encompass both http and https protocols, so probably just set them both.

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and created one project for all my websites (about 70 api keys).

We'll see how this go. I think it will be fine since there is no way even all of my websites together to reach 25,000 map requests per day.

Thanks for the help.